# Problem uploading a latin1 file in a utf-8 SAS

Tags: linux, encoding, sas

On a Linux system with SAS with ENCODING=UTF-8, I have this file:

```
more provab.txt
▒00CC00   ▒00CC00   S012016-10-04
▒00CC00   ▒00CC00   S012021-10-20

xxd provab.txt
0000000: b130 3043 4330 3020 2020 b130 3043 4330  .00CC00   .00CC0
0000010: 3020 2020 5330 3132 3031 362d 3130 2d30  0   S012016-10-0
0000020: 3420 0ab1 3030 4343 3030 2020 20b1 3030  4 ..00CC00   .00
0000030: 4343 3030 2020 2053 3031 3230 3231 2d31  CC00   S012021-1
0000040: 302d 3230 200a                           0-20 .
 
file -i provab.txt
provab.txt: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
```

If I load it in SAS without setting the encoding:

```
Filename inp "/mypath/provab.txt" ;
Data work.current_file;
Infile inp lrecl=33 DSD MISSOVER PAD firstObs=1;
Attrib campo_1 length=$10
format=$char10. informat=$char10. ;
Attrib campo_2 length=$10
format=$char10. informat=$char10.  ;
Attrib campo_3 length=$3
format=$char3. informat=$char3.   ;
Attrib chr_data length=$10
format=$char10. informat=$char10.      ;
  Input
        @1 campo_1 $char10.
        @11 campo_2 $char10.
        @21 campo_3 $char3.
        @24 chr_data $char10.
        ;
Run;
```

I get:

[image]

If I set `ENCODING= LATIN1`:

```
Filename inp "/mypath/provab.txt" 
ENCODING= LATIN1
;
Data work.current_file;
Infile inp lrecl=33 DSD MISSOVER PAD firstObs=1;
Attrib campo_1 length=$10
format=$char10. informat=$char10. ;
Attrib campo_2 length=$10
format=$char10. informat=$char10.  ;
Attrib campo_3 length=$3
format=$char3. informat=$char3.   ;
Attrib chr_data length=$10
format=$char10. informat=$char10.      ;
  Input
        @1 campo_1 $char10.
        @11 campo_2 $char10.
        @21 campo_3 $char3.
        @24 chr_data $char10.
        ;
Run;
```

I get:

[image]

As you can see, `campo_1` and `campo2` are displayed correctly but every "strange" chars implies a shift in the rest of the fields.

The `chr_date field`, for example, is shifted of 2 chars.

I get the same result also with `encoding='iso-8859-1'`.

And with `iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 provab.txt >provau.txt` and loading `provau.txt` I also get the same anomaly.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you tried `encoding='iso-8859-1'`?

Comment: @ChrisJ It gives the same result as latin1, unfortunately.

Comment: @ChrisJ: both are the exact same encoding. One with ISO standard number, the other as original name from ECMA.

Comment: Only a workaround, but many text editors can convert a text file from one encoding to a different one. For example vim or notepad++ can. You could try to convert your input file to utf-8 before loading it into SAS...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Unfortunately, it is a script that runs automatically at every file receiving for a file transfer. Is it possible to do a conversion in Linux before loading it in SAS?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I do not think it is a good way to do. As you see, the format has fixed width fields, and with UTF-8 (so with different size) you get thing wrong. Also original file is not UTF-8 (do not expect such obsolete format will handle UTF-8). @ CarLaTeX: do you have an idea on what should be the first character?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Indeed, with `iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 provab.txt >provau.txt` and loading `provau.txt` gives the same anomaly.
The first char is a + and - one over the other, see the second image in my question.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: You have got it! That is unfortunately what the internal conversion does and that is the reason for loosing characters...

Comment: As processing fixed length fields does not work with multibyte UTF-8, you can only _afterwards_ convert to UTF-8 - if the processing does not corrupt ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thank you, I will try to convert them after loading them in SAS.

Comment: Have you tried using the $UTF8X informat, instead of $CHAR?
https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/vdmmlcdc/8.1/nlsref/p0j36n03zapslgn13fgytqf80v3y.htm

Comment: @ChrisJ With $UTF8X informat it gives the same result as in the first image of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Joop Eggen's and other's comments and answer, I solved my problem using the SAS function `tranwrd` *after* loading the file.

This gives the desired result:

```
Filename inp "/mypath/provab.txt";

Data work.current_file;
Infile inp lrecl=33 DSD MISSOVER PAD firstObs=1;
Attrib campo_1 length=$10
format=$char10. informat=$char10. ;
Attrib campo_2 length=$10
format=$char10. informat=$char10.  ;
Attrib campo_3 length=$3
format=$char3. informat=$char3.   ;
Attrib chr_data length=$10
format=$char10. informat=$char10.      ;
  Input
        @1 campo_1 $char10.
        @11 campo_2 $char10.
        @21 campo_3 $char3.
        @24 chr_data $char10.
        ;
campo_1 = tranwrd(campo_1,'b1'x,'c2b1'x);
campo_2 = tranwrd(campo_2,'b1'x,'c2b1'x);
Run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After the comment from @GiacomoCatenazzi, I guess that when you give an encoding, the loader first does the charset conversion and only after split the data into fields. But as non ascii Latin1 characters are converted into 2 bytes in UTF-8, the conversion breaks the fixed size fields format.

That means that you will have to do a non trivial pre-processing:

- split every line into fixed size fields
- convert each field into UTF-8 charset
- combine back the fields with a padding maintaining the original width.

That would be trivial with a Python script and can probably be done with awk but IMHO you will not find a product for that.

Comment: Thank you, Serge. Your solution is quite complex because the real file is much more longer than the example I posted. However, I think I can do something similar in SAS, converting only the chars that give the anomaly.